# file is uploading two times when user clicks upload and if it takes more time to process

Tags: php, zend-framework, file-upload

when i am trying to upload excel sheet and process each row store it on my db. unfortunately this is not working when i am uploading larger data set. same file is uploading twice.   here is same code snippet.

```
     ignore_user_abort(true);
    $excelSheetReader = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
                    $excelSheetReader->read($_FILES['bulk_data']['tmp_name']);
                    $sheets = $excelSheetReader->sheets;


                    if(count($sheets)>0){
                        $sheets=$sheets[0];
                    }

                    if($sheets !=NULL) {

                        for ($x = 1; $x <= $sheets['numRows']; $x++) {

        set_time_limit(0); 
    //process each row
    }
}`
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The first possible cause to check is if the users actually *are* uploading the files twice. :) You should make sure users aren't accidentally uploading the file multiple times, for example by clicking "submit" twice.

If user error isn't the problem, then the next thing to look at is request type. What kind of request are you using to upload the file: `PUT` or a `POST`? A `PUT` is idempotent, which means the user's browser can repeat the request automatically if it hits an error, like timeout. `POST`, however, will never be retried without asking the user first.

If you're using a `PUT`, I'd suggest that you try changing the request type to `POST` and see if that helps.

Comment: users are uploading only once but the script is getting executed second time. and i am using POST request type.

Comment: Next stupid question: Does the code get run exactly once per `POST`, or could the code be getting run 2 times for 1 `POST` request? The next step I would take in debugging would be to prove that two separate `POST` requests are happening. If I can't prove that two separate `POST` requests are happening, I'd conclude that the code is getting called in some way that I don't expect.